# Cross-domain form posting with iframe target in Chrome

Tags: forms, google-chrome, jquery-validate, cross-domain

I have a form on that posts to a hidden iframe. The form's action URL is on a separate domain. I'm seeing a problem in Chrome where the form posts, but no form data is sent.

Here's the setup:

```
<form action="http://anotherdomain/save" method="post" target="myiframe" id="myform">
    <!-- standard form fields here -->
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<iframe src="about:blank" name="myiframe" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

If the user clicks the button, the form posts as it should into the iframe and all is good. If, however, I introduce jQuery Validation, things stop working in Chrome. I have my validation looking like this:

```
$("#myform").validate({
   // various options set here
   submitHandler: function(form) {
       form.submit();
       // stuff that should happen after the form submits
   }
});
```

In this scenario, form.submit() causes the form to submit without any data being posted, only the headers are sent. The content-length is always 0. This only happens in Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera all submit fine.

What's more strange is if I have another button on the page and I wire it up with the following code, the form submits properly.

```
$("myotherbutton").click(function() { $("#myform").submit(); }
```

I'm at a loss as to why Chrome behaves this way, and if there is a workaround. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore this question. It was not a problem with Chrome and event handlers, but rather one related to removing a DOM element before an event was called on it.